# Put data directly into DataTable or dot net object?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, .net-3.5

Currently, I just create an OLEDB connection, run a query on it and load the result set into a SSIS object. I don't know what this Object really is. After that, I load this Object into a DataTable in my C# code. Instead of doing all this, is there a way to directly load this result set into a data table ? Also, is there a way to get the number of rows in the result set from the object itself ? Right now, I load it into a data table and then get the number of rows as myDataTable.Rows.Count;

Thanks.

Comment: For more info on this issue, please visit (Good help by cozyroc) - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a3aa958b-aca6-4929-9693-316204d4df04/put-data-directly-into-datatable-or-dot-net-object-?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: OR - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1522969-148-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to use an ADO.NET connection instead of OLEDB. If you use ADO.NET connection, you will get ADO.NET DataSet object. A DataSet is a collection of DataTable.

Some links for DataSet tutorials -

http://www.dotnetperls.com/dataset

Scott Mitchell's tut -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx

Also, if you want to get the number of rows in your OLEDB resultset (actually an ADODB recordset) using C# , then use this -

```
using ADODB;

  ADODB.Recordset resultSet = (ADODB.Recordset)Dts.Variables["MyResultSet"].Value;
  int rows = resultSet.RecordCount;
```

Don't for get to add a reference to ADODB as follows – 
Solution Explorer > References > COM tab > Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.X Library > OK.
File menu > Save All